# Sharing a Base64 image directly to facebook and other social media

Tags: javascript, php, html, base64, share

So I've got a base64 PNG image, and want to share that directly to social media, without saving it into the server. However, social media accepts only URL's and does not accept the base64 string. Is there a way to share the image directly? The following code doesn't work:

```
href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?display=popup&u=data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB......"
```

Comment: I don't think what you want is actually possible in that manner, or at all. You could perform an upload, but that would require permissions.